# Angular Route Infinite loop, I think

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

So basically the issue is that when I open the page it just freezes and uses something like 30% of my CPU (4 core CPU so a whole core), cant click anything on the page or even bring up F12.

If it's a page that has a data request on load then I can see in fiddler that it'll spam which makes me think it's somehow on an infinite loop. However I was working on it last night without this issue, so I decided to roll back to the latest version which still somehow has this problem which makes me think that it might not be Angular Router since I havn't changed it since before my last commit. Below is my routing setup.
You may notice how some of the paths of the routing are slightly different, I was trying to see if this was the issue but each one results in the problem

This is running on a ASP.NET Web Api 2 as the Server and with Angular 1.5.

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/TimeFeed',
        {
            templateUrl: '/View/Templates/TimeFeed.html',
            controller: 'timeFeedController'
        }
    );
    $routeProvider.when('/CharacterLookup',
        {
            templateUrl: '/View/Templates/CharacterLookup.html',
            controller: 'characterLookupController'
        }
    );
    $routeProvider.when('/RealmStatus',
        {
            templateUrl: '/View/Templates/RealmStatus.html',
            controller: 'realmStatusController'
        }
    );
    $routeProvider.when('/ContactUs',
        {
            templateUrl: '/View/Templates/ContactUs.html',
            controller: 'contactUsController'
        }
    );
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/CharacterLookup' });
});
```

Any idea what could cause this? if it's not my routing settings?

Update: Tthis is one of the controllers that it's failing on

App.controller('contactUsController',
    function contactUsController($scope, $http) {

```
    $scope.subject = "";
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    $scope.disableSend = false;
    $scope.alerts = [];
    $scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.sendMessage = function () {
        $scope.disableSend = true;
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        var url = "/api/Tools/SendEmailToAdmin?subject=" + $scope.subject + "&message="+$scope.message;
        var data = $.param({
            subject: $scope.subject,
            message: $scope.message
        });
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.post(url, config)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.subject = "";
                $scope.message = "";
                $scope.alerts.push({
                    type: 'success',
                    msg: 'Message successfully sent'
                })
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.alerts.push({
                    type: 'danger',
                    msg: 'Message failed to send sent'
                });
                console.error("failed to get data");
            }).finally(function() {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.disableSend = false;
            });
    }
});
```

Updated routes with what im currently trying

The Screen shot below is happened when I tried loading it in Firefox. As you can see it cascades down repeating the page inside the page each time

[image]

**Update:**
Well I found the problem. A while back I changed my file structure a little bit to tidy things up, well I missed changing the template path of one of my directives but since when you hit ctrl f5 in chrome it dosen't reload the files it's pulling from so I guess today that file did get reloaded and the path wasn't correct which caused angular to have a spaz. I wish Angular would tell you what's actually going on rather than just crash

Comment: Things looks good with your routes, can you provide us with the Ctrl code of the view you stuck in ?

Comment: @Druid 1 sec, ill update post, however it's happening on all pages

Comment: Remove the line  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/ContactUs' }); see if it gets better?

Comment: @AwakeningByte tried doing that without change

Comment: it is hard to see any problem here. I can only suggest to temporally remove all routes except the ContactUs. Then add back one by one.

Comment: @AwakeningByte Yeah fair enough man, im a bit lost on this one, I'm think it might actually be casued by asp.net somehow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change this

```
$louteProvider.when('/ContactUs',
```

to this

```
$routeProvider.when('/ContactUs',
```

Comment: Ok so that's a typo on here, somehow in the copy paste it got messed up becasue it's `$routeProvider.when('/ContactUs',` in my code, probably when I was formatting or something. As for ui-router, i've heard it being mentioned a lot but didn't think it could provide much advantages over the Angular one( if that's how it works) but ill look into now anyway. I updated the post with that im currently trying